# Ошибка 500 при переносе битрикс на хостинг

Tags: php, битрикс

Полностью перенес сайт на сервер, подключил указал данные для подключения бд, в php.ini разрешил короткие теги. Всё равно выдаёт ошибку 500.
Вот лог:

> [Mon May 15 14:43:19.549734 2023] [php7:notice] [pid 3724] [client 79.133.164.26:58180] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'RandomSequence' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in /var/www/zoosat_acidh_usr/data/www/zoosat.acidhead.ru/bitrix/modules/main/lib/orm/query/filter/conditiontree.php on line 42

Comment: Подождем телепатов, может они подскажут что там на 42 строке.

Comment: Возможно https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/forums/forum6/topic149518/

Comment: @u_mulder, код полностью исправен и корректен, на локалке всё ок работает

Comment: @ViVi ну-ну, давай спорить с пеной у рта, что "на локалке робит" вместо того, чтобы посмотреть что не так...